# Output buffer in PHP won't work

Tags: php, output-buffering

For some time (serveral nights..) I've been trying to get a time-expensive script to output simple dots so I know it's still processing the script. Basically it's a cronjob which is going to run nightly to update cache-keys in a memcache server.

No matter what I try I can't get PHP to output the current buffer. What I want is to send the echo'd dots while processing the script. What am I missing to get it to work? I've also tried the `flush()` function... and also to use `ini_set("output_buffering", 1024);`

At the moment this is my set up:

```
# clean all open buffers    
while(ob_get_level() != 0)
{
    ob_end_clean(); 
}

ob_start();

// Several loops, taking some minutes...
for( ..loopconditions ..){
echo ".";
ob_flush();
}

ob_end_clean()
```

Comment: Is it on a Windows or Apache server?

Comment: you running the script in CLI/terminal or browser? in default configed cli a echo goes directly to stdout, simple test: <?php echo "before\n"; sleep(60); echo "after\n"; ?>

Comment: The script slept for 60 seconds, and then outputted both 'before' and 'after'.

Comment: Use BOTH `flush()` and `ob_flush()`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you debugging this in a browser? If so, it may not be a problem with the output buffering at all.

Every browser has a buffer of it's own and ultimately it decides when to start flushing it.

Mentioned in the manual page for [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php):

> flush() ... has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser.
>
> Even the browser may buffer its input before displaying it. Netscape, for example, buffers text until it receives an end-of-line or the beginning of a tag, and it won't render tables until the  tag of the outermost table is seen.
>
> Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I've read the docs in your link. Still don't know how to fix it.. I've tried it in Chrome, FF and Safari (No IE available).

Comment: Just for testing, try flushing a bunch of gibberish beforehand (perhaps a Lipsum paragraph). See if it works then.

Comment: It doesn't work.. :( See the comment in start post as well. It just seems to be ignored... and put to the browser when the end of the script is reached.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, if you're using php-cgi, output buffering doesn't work.

Comment: Run the phpinfo() function.  In one of the first sections, you'll see something like "Server API".  If you're running the CGI version of PHP, it'll say so.

Answer (score 0):

In console, it is easier to use [PEAR Console_ProgressBar](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_ProgressBar). It will do it for you.

Example from the docs:

```
<?php
require_once 'Console/ProgressBar.php';
$bar = new Console_ProgressBar('[%bar%] %percent%', '=>', ' ', 80, 7);

//do some processing here
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $bar->update($i);
    sleep(1);
}
echo "\n";
?>

[=======================================>                              ]  57.14%
```

More examples in:

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-progressbar.php#example-124

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.console.console-progressbar.php#example-125

Comment: That is a bit too much to get it to work. I know it can work, and I want to display it in a browser. I've seen it before. Installing/using a package for this matter seems a bit heavy... Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: if in browser then the issue is you need to call both ob_flush() & flush() together.